# How does KProperty1 transform into a lambda?

Tags: kotlin, lambda, casting

I have the following code which works as expected -

```
data class Customer(val id: Int, val name: String)
val initialCustomers = arrayOf(Customer(1, "Kotlin"), Customer(2, "Spring"), Customer(3, "Microservice"))
val customers = ConcurrentHashMap<Int, Customer>(initialCustomers.associateBy(Customer::id))
```

What I don't understand is how

```
Customer::Id
```

which is of is of type

```
KProperty1<Customer,Int>
```

Somehow accepted by initialCustomers.associatedBy() function, which is meant to take a lambda as a parameter.

Can someone explain that to me? Is it that KProperty1 has a base definition of (T)-> R, and therefore contains an implict casting from that type to a lambda of that matching type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As can be seen from the source, the interface `KProperty1<T, R>` is declared as inheriting from `(T) -> R`:

```
public actual interface KProperty1<T, out R> : KProperty<R>, (T) -> R {
    ...
}
```

This allows an object of type `KProperty1<T, R>` to be used in place of a lambda.

From implementation side, inheritance from `(T) -> R` means that any class implementing `KProperty1` should provide an implementation of `operator fun invoke(t: T): R`.  For example, `KProperty1Impl` implements it as follows:

```
override fun invoke(receiver: T): R = get(receiver)
```

Read more about the `invoke` operator [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#invoke).

Comment: Makes total sense now. Thanks!